# Always null inputstream

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to implement login activity using a script. The script is working and I have already tested the script in postman application. I am sending the data in json format and the server sends response in json format. When I try to read the response, It is always null. Can someone please help.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String data="";
        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject Data=new JSONObject();
        try {
            Data.put("service","emailsignin");
            Data.put("email_id",mEmail);
            Data.put("password",mPassword);
            Data.put("device_token","ABCD");
            Data.put("device_type","A");
            Data.put("user_type_id","2");
            jsonobj.put("data",Data);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        String write_data=String.valueOf(jsonobj);
        Log.e("write_data:",write_data);
        try {
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
          writer.write(write_data);
          writer.close();
          InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
          reader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("LoginActivity:",inputLine);
                buffer.append(inputLine).append("\n");
            }
            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                Log.e("LoginActivity:","input string empty");
                return null;
            }
            data = buffer.toString();

            Log.e("Response is:",data);
            try {

                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;


        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Log In:", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;


    }
```

Comment: You might just need to add the following property:
    `httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: Be accurate. There is no 'always null input stream' or 'response ... is always null' here. What there is is an *empty* response, which is *translated* by *your code* to null. Or possibly an `IOException` which you haven't reported here, after which, again, *your code* returns null. A `try/catch` around a mere `return` statement is completely pointless.

Answer (score -1):

you can use some libraries that do server request for you like [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). I think some thing wrong with your request. or you can use this method to post json to server(you will need org.apache.http jar or add it by gradle):

```
public static String POST(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        //your json fields fill here

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```